# Apple Watch no longer displays temperature

Tags: apple-watch, temperature

Since I installed the most recent Apple Watch software version (early April, 2016) the temperature no longer appears on the watch face (-- appears), yet when I press the temperature (on the Apple Watch), it successfully loads the weather channel data.  Why does the temperature no longer appear on the watch face?

Answer (score 2):

I've had this issue and I did the following:

1. Restarting by holding down both the Digital Crown and Friends button.
2. Erasing and restoring the Apple Watch from backup.
3. Erasing and setting Apple Watch up as new

I hope 1 or 2 works for you, because I unfortunately had to set it up as new.

Answer (score 2):

I did restart, but still did not work. I opened my weather app on iPhone and that fixed the problem. The weather app seems buggy with the latest update.

Answer (score 1):

I have to continually switch to the next watch face over and then back again, and that fixes it.  Only since the last update.  Annoying.

Answer (score 0):

- Do you have a location set up in Weather for iOS?
- Is your watch connected to iPhone or WiFi?

Those are two reasons why it may not show correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Location is set up properly and watch is connected to iPhone.  Still no temperature appears on watch face.

Answer (score 0):

Try that hard restart (the current iteration of the watch OS doesn't have a "friends" button), and then set your watch location to either a town close by or—best, if that works—"present location."  I just coaxed mine to register the temperature that way.  I live in a town that doesn't register on the Apple map, for some reason, but when I set the watch to "current location," the name of the town popped up.  If the location you want is greyed out, that's a clue.  02/18

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the app at that location on your watch face to another app, from the Watch app on your iphone. Then change it back to the weather app. Just worked.